# How to mapping jdbc data to xsd Schema

Tags: xml, database, xsd, mule

Present I am working on different scenarios in db operations (`select`, `insert` and `update`).

Now we have some requirements, i.e mapping database schema based on XSD Schema. How to work with xsd in Mule esb. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, the easiest one is probably: https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/5/defining-datamapper-input-and-output-metadata#using-an-xsd-schema-definition

Comment: Romero, thank you for ur response. And also I gone through the above link. I get some information.